# Placing the Resource tag inside conf/context.xml gets an exception but is okay when I place the same  inside META-INF/context.xml : Why is that?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, context.xml

To connect to derby database using tomcat as the server initially I added the following to `conf/context.xml` of Tomcat :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/PollDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
 url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/poll database;create=true"
 username="suhail" password="suhail"
 maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

and the `Resource-ref` tag in web.xml of the `WEB-INF/web.xml` of the project.

```
<resource-ref>
<description>my connection</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/PollDatasource</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

But when I ran a servlet that had to connect to the database,the statement :

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

caused an exception :

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

I haven't understood the reason for this exception *yet*.

After the exception I removed the `Resource` tag from the `conf/context.xml` of the Tomcat and placed it in the `META-INF/context.xml` of my project.

*When I tried the servlet again,it worked without any exception !*

What could be the reason I am getting the exception when I place the `Resource` tag inside the global context.xml file *(i.e inside conf/context.xml)* but do not get the exception when I place it inside the context.xml specific to my application ?. *(i.e inside META-INF/context.xml)*

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<Resource>` to `conf/context.xml` will make a copy of that resource available for every webapp you deploy on your server -- probably not what you want to do. If you want a `<Resource>` to be globally available, it's more appropriate to put it into `conf/server.xml` under `<GlobalNamiongResources>`.

I would expect that the error you are getting is because you don't have your JDBC driver in the right place. Defining the `<Resource>` in `conf/context.xml` may result in a different ClassLoader being used to load your `<Resource>`.

Comment: what do you actually mean by `JDBC` driver ? I have the driver to connect to the derby database inside the _lib_ folder of _tomcat_.

Comment: I mean the JAR file for the JDBC driver. See your other question you posted that is nearly identical to this one.

Comment: The drivers needed to run have been in their place : inside the _lib_ folder of tomcat

Comment: you didn't tell the reason for the exception when the drivers are there in the right place ....

Comment: I'm sorry I can't inspect your entire configuration. Every time this error has occurred, checking the JDBC driver and, if necessary, completely re-writing the `<Resource>` definition has fixed the problem. I have also seen slightly mismatched JNDI names cause this kind of problem.